How to update python verison in Ubuntu?
I want to update Python 3.7.12 to 3.10 in google cloud. I successfuly downloaded and installed python 3.10. Using sudo update-alternatives I want to activate Python 3.10. What is the correct declaration of sudo update-alternatives in this case? These are the locations of Python 3.7 and 3.10 :
(base) jupyter@kamil-a-tokyo:~$ which python3
/opt/conda/bin/python3
(base) jupyter@kamil-a-tokyo:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.12
(base) jupyter@kamil-a-tokyo:~$ python3.10 --version
Python 3.10.0
(base) jupyter@kamil-a-tokyo:~$ which python3.10
/usr/local/bin/python3.10


I think you should remove /opt/conda/bin from the PATH or upgrade Anaconda instead

As OneCricketeer references, you have two Pythons here. You can use conda install and specify the the version you want. You may also be able to activate the environments and leave the local/bin where it is. Conda is more feature rich than the system installed one, i.e., local/bin one. However, you have to read about the getting started with Anaconda/conda stuff and manage the environment properly. See here for more about that. But it can be tricky if you don't take the time to understand it.

I created a new environment in anaconda and activated it with python 3.10. Now it's ok except I get {"code":-1021,"msg":"Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow."} when I try to connect binance

You could try putting alias python3=python3.10 to your bashrc file. This would simply make python3 an alias of python3.10. This is not really updating the python version, rather fooling the system into using a different command which calls a newer version.
In Linux, the version of a package cannot exceed the newest version which is in the package manager. So if your package manager only supports up to python 3.7, you can’t install python 3.10 using apt. However, you can compile from source (I wouldn’t) or use the installer on the python website (python.org)
